# What is the best place to place the constants strings in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an iOS app, this is my first experience in app development. I like to get you peoples suggestions to build the app in a standardize manner. Can anyone tell me what is the best place to put the constant strings?

for now i am using the constants in this way #define __string @"string"
is that ok?

Comment: How many implementation files need to see these constants?

Comment: Constants are generally written in uppercase, words seperated by underscore(`_`)

Comment: almost 10 to 15 files

Comment: If they are only `#define`s then you could put them into a header file, that's `#import`ed from these implementation files.  If they require definition somewhere (i.e. `extern NSString * const someString;` etc, and there are many of them then use a header and implementation file.

Comment: Ok thank you. And what is the best place to do validation?  for instance: if i have a form with the fields: name, age etc. And i don't have a save button. when the user transfer from one view controller to another, his details should be saved automatically. I am doing the validation in didFieldEndEditing is that okay? or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create constant header file first after define your constant as macro then import to where you want through access your constant

[image]

Comment: why minus...............

Comment: This is good resolving... I wanted to write the same thing, in my projects I use always that formed Globals.h class for const values.

Answer (score 0):

I put them in the [APP_NAME]-prefix.pch file like this:

`#define SERVICE_BASE_URL @"http://url.com"`